# Vim NERDTree not working

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Encountered a strange bug. I cannot open directories/files in NERDTree when I double click or press o. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was because I was on a more "exotic" shell. `set shell=/bin/bash` did the trick for me.

Comment: mark you answer as best answer ....

Comment: I'm already using bash, and I'm getting exactly this. Out of nowhere. :/

Answer (score 0):

I get this exact problem, but only when calling vim from an alias in .bashrc

`alias vim='toolbox run -c dcxxxxxx vim'`

However, typing

`toolbox enter vim`

at the cli, I have no problem.

The NERDTree plugin is installed correctly as

`sudo dnf install vim-nerdtree`

I am running Fedora Silverblue 36